# How to sort an abstract class object

Tags: c++, sorting, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a base abstract class of Shapes, and 3 derived class of Circle Square and Rectangle. After calculating the areas of all the shapes i'm required to sort them. I am having difficulties using std::sort in the  library to sort as my Shapes is an abstract class. 
Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction of what i'm doing wrong.

I have tried operator overloading, declaring my own comparator function.

```
#define MAX 100
class ShapeTwoD
{
protected: 
    string name;
    double area;

public:
    ShapeTwoD() {}
    ShapeTwoD(string name, double area);
    virtual ~ShapeTwoD() {}

    string getName();

    virtual string toString();

    virtual double getArea() = 0;
    virtual void setArea(double area) = 0;
    virtual double computeArea() = 0;
};
bool sortAsc(ShapeTwoD *s1, ShapeTwoD *s2)
{
    return s1->getArea() < s2->getArea();
}



class Square: public ShapeTwoD
{
public:
    Square() {}
    Square(string name, double area);
    ~Square() {}

    virtual double getArea();
    virtual void setArea(double area);

    virtual string toString();

    virtual double computeArea();
};

int main()
{
   ShapeTwoD * ShapeArray[MAX];
   string name;
   double area;
   int Shapeindex;
   for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
        cin << name;
        cin << area;
        if (name == "Square" || name == "square")
        {
            ShapeArray[Shapeindex] = new Square(name, area);
        }
    Shapeindex++;
    }
    sort(ShapeArray, ShapeArray + MAX, sortAsc);
}
```

Actual Result of above code: Read Access Violation Error, I'm assuming its because i'm trying to read the area from my abstract class instead of my derived class.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: How is `ShapeArray` populated? As far as one can see from your current example, it contains `MAX` amount of uninitialized pointers. Dereferencing any of those leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Please include definition of `Shape`, `Circle`, `Square` and `Rectangle` as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver i edited the question with more information.

Comment: @KunalPuri I just edited the question to show more information

Comment: @NewPea There is still not enough.  Do you reeally do `sort(ShapeArray, ShapeArray + MAX, sortAsc);
    ShapeTwoD * ShapeArray[MAX];`?  I should be able to copy and paste the code you post into my compiler and compile it.  I can't do that with the code you've posted.  Please post a minimal example that is compileable.

Comment: @NathanOliver ah okay i get what you mean now. ill changed it

Comment: @NewPea Please include declaration of `ShapeIndex` as well.

Comment: @NewPea Is `ShapeIndex` initialized to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, it seems to be the problem related to `sort(ShapeArray, ShapeArray + MAX, sortAsc);`.

If your `Shapeindex` variable is less than `MAX` value, then accessing elements from index `Shapeindex + 1` till `MAX` have Undefined Behaviour which may lead to segmentation fault.

Instead, you should do this:

```
sort(ShapeArray, ShapeArray + Shapeindex, sortAsc);
```

Comment: I encountered this problem when i was trying to compute area and i changed MAX to Shapeindex, but somehow i miss this when the error appeared. Thank You!

Comment: This problem would not has arisen if you'd used a vector instead of an array, Vectors are easier and more powerful, use them.

Answer (score 3):

(After the latest update): You're creating 10 `ShapeTwoD` objects, but sorting 100 (`MAX`) pointers.

Comment: Most likely this isn't what the OP actually has, they just paraphrased it.  We should really wait for a [mcve] before answering.